# jQuery ajax handle response with .html()

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

My Java controller gets data from the form and sends back a JSON boolean result:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/save", ... )
@ResponseBody
public boolean savePerson(...) {
    ...
    return jpaPersonService.savePersonService(person);
}
```

JS on form's submit button:

```js
$('#savePersonForm').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/person/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#savePersonForm').serialize(),
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("ajax success");
            console.log("response: " + response);
            $('#result').html(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error(s):' + textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

In both cases when my controller sends back `true/false` I can see `response: true` or `response: false`. So I'm sure that JS gets an answer.

My next step is to add this answer into the div `#result`. If it is `true` - all is fine. If it is `false` I get an empty div. After some tests I've got that if I add text to the `response` it's working: `$('#result').html(response + '');`.
I'm using jquery-2.1.4.min.js.

Do I have a mistake somewhere or is that supposed to be like that ? Thank you.

Comment: What does your page's HTML look like?

Comment: How does response looks in `console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are attempting to set the `html()` of an element to the boolean `false` value which [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/L5cjkfts/) (even though `true` does - I guess there is an inconsistency in the jQuery source here).

To fix this you need to force the boolean type to be coerced to a string. Try this:

```
$('#result').html('' + response);
```

Or

```
$('#result').html(response.toString()); // if supported
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5cjkfts/1/)

Comment: Yes, same as I wrote that it works when I'm forcing boolean to string with `response + ''`. I was wondering why does it work with `true` though. Could that be kind of bug in the query code ? Anyway, thank you for your reply!

Comment: From looking at the [source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.fn.html) I would guess it's to do with either the `rnoInnerhtml` or `wrapMap` returning nothing for `false`.